# MongoDB + PHP: Error "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017"

Tags: php, database, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have running a EC2 instance with MongoDB and some .php files to deploy a little webpage.
PHP shows productos taken from MongoDB.

```php
<?php
include_once("header.php");
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$uri="mongodb://localhost";
$client=new MongoDB\Client($uri);

$collection = $client->tienda->categorias->find();
$categorias=array();
```

When I created DB it was no problem. After a new login to EC2 webpage doesn't show anything from DB.
When I try to check DB this error returns:

```
> use tienda
> show collections
2020-05-13T17:29:29.612+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2020-05-13T17:29:29.612+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-05-13T17:29:29.612+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed failed
2020-05-13T17:29:29.612+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
runClientFunctionWithRetries@src/mongo/shell/session.js:346:31
runCommand@src/mongo/shell/session.js:412:25
DB.prototype._runCommandImpl@src/mongo/shell/db.js:145:16
DB.prototype.runCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:161:20
DB.prototype._getCollectionInfosCommand@src/mongo/shell/db.js:930:19
DB.prototype.getCollectionInfos@src/mongo/shell/db.js:953:19
DB.prototype.getCollectionNames@src/mongo/shell/db.js:964:16
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:809:9
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:706:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
2020-05-13T17:24:05.117+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed
2020-05-13T17:24:05.117+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-05-13T17:24:05.117+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1) failed failed
```

After some google hours the only way I found to keep DB working is running on a new tab

```
$ mongod
```

Once I close this tab, DB stops to work and webpay stops to display products.
Is there any way to fix this?
I'm new to MongoDB btw.

Comment: mongod is just running the MongoDB process. You can't connect to MongoDB if it's not running. You can run it in another terminal tab like you've been doing, or there are a variety of methods you could use to run it in the background. This is a Linux question, not a MongoDB issue.

Simplest way to run in the background: `mongod &` (with the ampersand) However, if you want to always have MongoDB running on Amazon Linux, look into learning systemd commands. (The command `sudo systemctl enable mongod; sudo systemctl start mongod` *might* work but I haven't tried it...might be just `mongo`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the MongoDB process as a daemon

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

Where logpath is where logs will be saved.

Documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Comment: Thanks you! 
I had to create dir `$ mkdir ~/log` and it works!